# Why does \maketitle remove my footer?

Tags: header-footer, titles, article

I had a nice footer that I used for a letter, and wanted to reuse it in an article in which I want to include title, author and date as well...

Now I find that if I include the title, author and date, my footer disappears... Why is this happening? How do I get it back?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% Footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{1cm}
\fancyfoot[L]{\textbf{Lorem ipsum footer}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}


%\author{John Doe}
%\date{\today}
%\title{Lorem ipsum text}


\begin{document}
%\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{document}
```

See the footer disappear if you uncomment title, author, date, and maketitle

Comment: `\maketitle\thispagestyle{fancy}` or `\fancypagestyle{plain}{<your definition here>}`.

Comment: Alright! \maketitle\thispagestyle{fancy} worked perfectly! thanks!